# Zenoss multi-graph reports for a location or group of servers

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, zenoss

we are using ZenOss with the HP server zenpacks to monitor our servers.
I want to create a multi-graph report for the thermal monitors in the servers.
I can successfully create a report when using "specific device/component" and selecting a server and its temperature sensors (cpu1, cpu2, ioboard1 etc).
How can I apply this when using an organizer for the collection such as one form systems, locations or groups?

When using specific device/component the datapoint for the graph definition is      TemperatureCelsius_temperature_celsius but I cannot see how to specify the datapoint when using groups of servers. I tried using the same as above but the graph does not display.

Do I need to specify something like ${device/hw/cpu1}TemperatureCelsius_temperature_celsius and if so how, as it doesnt seem to work.

The end result I want is a single graph plotting the temperature of a sensor from each server in the organizer.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After you add a collection, under Graph Definitions select add graph give it a name.

When you add the data point to the graph definition you just need to add the full datapoint name no host is needed.

For example to see used blocks for a file system you would use usedBlock_usedBlock.

You can find the datapoint names by looking under the monitoring templates, selecting the graph definition selecting manage graph points edit the data point and look under the datapoint field.

DataPoint:
usedBlocks_usedBlocks

FWIW I'm on Zenoss 3.1.0

Also I recommend joining in IRC on (freenode #zenoss).